# How to parcel StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, exception, android-notifications

I'm developing an Android application where I have a Service communicating with an Activity. 
I have a Parcelable class that has a StatusBarNotification in it. I wrote the parcel code in this way:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
    out.writeParcelable(mNotification, 0);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<NotificationAdapter> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<NotificationAdapter>() {
    @Override
    public NotificationAdapter createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new NotificationAdapter(in);
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationAdapter[] newArray(int size) {
        return new NotificationAdapter[size];
    }
};

private NotificationAdapter(Parcel in) {
    mNotification = StatusBarNotification.CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
}
```

But it is causing an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to unparcel Bitmap
at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1647)
at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1637)
at android.widget.RemoteViews$BitmapCache.<init>(RemoteViews.java:1034)
at android.widget.RemoteViews.<init>(RemoteViews.java:2089)
at android.widget.RemoteViews.<init>(RemoteViews.java:2081)
at android.widget.RemoteViews$3.createFromParcel(RemoteViews.java:3227)
at android.widget.RemoteViews$3.createFromParcel(RemoteViews.java:3225)
at android.app.Notification.<init>(Notification.java:1484)
at android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification.<init>(StatusBarNotification.java:83)
at android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification$1.createFromParcel(StatusBarNotification.java:135)
at android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification$1.createFromParcel(StatusBarNotification.java:132)
```

Am I doing it wrongly? Can someone help me with this issue?
Thanks :)

Comment: Ps.: mNotification is my StatusBatNotification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private NotificationAdapter(Parcel in) {
    mNotification = in.readParcelable(StatusBarNotification.class.getClassLoader());
}
```